# Flash Video Decodes Incorrectly

Tags: windows-7, video, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash-player

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit on an Asus 1215N laptop Google Chrome and Internet Explorer with Adobe Flashplayer 10.1. Recently I've noticed that I'll have errors in my flash video.

If it exists on video load, it exists for the duration of the video. If it does not exist on video load, it never happens. It rarely happens for the first video I play, but usually happens for the second. I notice this effect on multiple websites that play flash video, including YouTube, and gomtv.net. However, I've never experienced this with YouTube HTML5 videos, or with any sort of videos played locally through VLC (even if they're copies of the ones giving me the problems on youtube). I don't know if this is a hardware or a software issue.

As for the error itself, it seems that some colours are vertically offset. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be a bug in the video drivers attempting to accelerate video playback.

Try checking Windows Update for newer video card drivers, or the Asus website.

Comment: Youch! After installing the intel integrated graphics drivers from the ASUS website, it lost recognition of my screen (to Generic PnP display device) and refused to use the (native) 16x9 aspect ratio. System restore managed to bring it back from that horribleness. Perhaps I should just call up ASUS. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check Windows update, under the "Optional" updates section?

Comment: Yeah. It was entirely up to date.

Comment: It was almost certainly a video driver issue. I think they may have been corrupted. I couldn't get them to properly re-install, so I reset the entire thing back to factory defaults, and it seems my problem is fixed. (And nothing of value was lost)